# Getting "302 Found" even after redirecting to a specific file in the .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, redirect, useragent

I have an Apache server hosted on an EC2 instance which points to a domain that I own. Now, what I essentially want to get done is that the web server should return a `.json` file when the user tries to curl the domain.

eg. `$curl mydomain.com`

My `000-default.conf` file which is located in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` looks as follows. I've added the `<Directory>` section to activate the `.htaccess` file located in my `/var/www/html` folder which is also the root of my website.

```
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

My `.htaccess` file looks as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCo "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" curl
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "/var/www/html/resume.json" [L,R=302]
```

My `/var/www/html` directory looks something like this:

```
/.well-known
.htaccess
index.html
resume.json
```

I've gone through numerous examples and tutorials and have used bits and pieces from everywhere to reach so far as I need something specific to be done. Unfortunately, when I try to curl my domain I get returned by the following message.

```
C:\Users\example >curl example.com/
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://example.com">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at example.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong in terms of configuration that I cannot get the `.json` displayed as it is on the terminal.

Comment: Why not copy/paste the text into your question, rather than linking to "screen grabs"?

Comment: Some people cannot see images. Please copy and paste text instead of making screenshots whenever possible.

Comment: Cheers, Will keep that in mind next time and try to avoid screenshots whenever possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using CURL, you need to use the `-L` flag to *follow* redirects, otherwise you will just see the redirect response, which is what you are seeing. (Since that is what your `.htaccess` directive is doing.)

However, there are errors in your `.htaccess` file...

Your `.htaccess` file (from your "screen grab"):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCo "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" curl
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "/var/www/html/resume.json" [L,R=302]
```

That `RewriteCo` line is an obvious syntax error - so I assume that can't be in your actual file?

- `"/var/www/html/resume.json"` - In `.htaccess`, the `RewriteRule` *substitution* takes a URL-path (relative to the document root) - you have supplied an absolute filesystem path, which won't work.
- `^(.*)$` - Your `RewriteRule` *pattern* also matches *everything*, so this will result in a redirect loop. If you only want to redirect the document root then you should use `^$` instead.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} curl
RewriteRule ^$ /resume.json [R=302,L]
```

However, do you really want to *externally redirect* the request? This should probably be an *internal rewrite*:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /resume.json [T=application/json,L]
```

---

*Aside:* It looks like your `<Directory>` section is "floating" outside of your `<VirtualHost>` container - shouldn't this be inside the vhost?

Comment: spot on! Thank you for your time. I've got it working now but curl requires "-L" flag without which it still says "302 Found". Is there a way to work around it so that I only have to type "curl example.com" without the "-L" flag and still get the desired output?

Also, yes the <Directory> section has to go outside my <VirtualHost>, I just checked and it didn't work when i tried otherwise.

Comment: As mentioned above, you can change this to an _internal rewrite_ instead of an _external redirect_. But if you keep it as a "redirect" then you will always need to include the `-L` flag with cURL.

Comment: well it is set to the latter RewriteRule that you've mentioned but still requires "-L" flag. I'm unsure why is this the case.

Comment: The later, as in `RewriteRule ^$ /resume.json [T=application/json,L]`? That is entirely internal to your server, there is no "redirect". This should not require the `-L` flag. Make sure you are not seeing a cached response from your server.

Comment: yes it is `RewriteRule ^$ /resume.json [T=application/json,L]` but still requires -L

Comment: If you don't use the `-L` flag what response do you get?

Comment: `C:\Users\user.name>curl ------b.me
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://-----b.me">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at -----b.me Port 80</address>
</body></html>`

Comment: I've also restarted the server after making changes to the file. just to be sure.

Comment: The redirect you are seeing seems to be an HTTP to HTTPS redirect, unrelated to the above. You need to include the protocol in the request, ie. `curl https://example.com`.

Comment: yes, got it! Thanks a ton!. Are there any beginner friendly tutorials that you could point me to? I want to learn this stuff(configurations etc). Seems pretty interesting. DOCs seem overwhelming at the moment.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. I'm not sure off hand, but you've touched on quite a few different topics here... HTTP, cURL, Apache, mod_rewrite.

Comment: yes! well i could have done this on Caddy Server with just about 2 lines of configuration but that seemed too easy. Apache was quite a bit of task to play with. Thanks to you! have been playing with it for a few days now without any better results.